# JAWT_LOCK_ERROR when trying to acquire lock from JAWT_DrawingSurface

Tags: java, java-native-interface, awt, x11, jniwrapper

## Introduction

I'm using JNIWrapper, and the JAWT subcomponent of that library.

I'm trying to acquire the lock on a [JAWT_DrawingSurface](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jniwrapper/javadoc/com/jniwrapper/jawt/JAWT_DrawingSurface.html) with the following code:

```
JAWT_DrawingSurface *ds = NULL;
ds = awt.GetDrawingSurface(env, comp);
dsLocked = !(ds->Lock(ds) & JAWT_LOCK_ERROR)
```

But I keep getting `dsLocked` to be false.

## Details

`comp` is sent to this JNIWrapper code from Java by the following:

```
Component panel = new VideoViewport().getDisplay();
panel.setBounds(150,150,150,150);
System.out.println("Handle: " + core.utils.X11.X11Utils.getDrawable(panel));
```

There's not much done to `panel` either by running `VideoViewport()` or by `getDisplay()`, and I don't know what details would be relevant.

## Question

What sort of things would cause acquiring the lock on the surface to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Component must be added to a frame and made visible.

When I added the Component to a AWT `Frame` object and made it visible before the `getDrawable(panel)` call, it worked and I was able to acquire the lock on the surface.